Display two HTML Tables side-by-side in Excel using PHP Spreadsheet
I am trying to display two tables side by side in an excel worksheet but the tables are getting displayed one below each other, is there a particular format I need to follow while writing the html code for PHP Spreadsheet, because if we see that same table in the browser it is properly getting displayed, Please Help
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Html;





$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$reader = new Html();


$HtmlString = '
    <table><tr><td>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Hello World 1</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td></tr>
</table></td>
<td>
<table border="1">
<tr><td>Hello World 2</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td><td>Hello World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td><td>Hello<br />World</td></tr>
<tr><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td><td>Hello<br>World</td></tr>
</table></td></tr></table>';
$spreadsheet = $reader->loadFromString($firstHtmlString);
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();



$sheet->getStyle('A1:D10')->applyFromArray([
    'borders' => [

        'allborders' => [
            'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THICK,
        ],


    ],
    'alignment' => [
        'horizontal' => Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        'vertical' => Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER,
    ],
    'font' => [
        'name' => 'Arial',
        'size' => 12,
        'italic' => true,
    ],

]);



$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="data.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer->save('php://output');

This the code that I have written to get HTML table to a excel worksheet side-by-side, and applied a little bit of styling

Just don't use HTML.

I have to make very big big tables, and doing them manually will take hell lot of time, and I have the html code for those tables already ready
